# TypeError: Socket is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, constructor, ftp-client

I'm new to Angular/Node and cannot seem to figure out a problem I'm having.

I'm trying to connect to an ftp using [client-ftp](https://github.com/noodny/node-ftp-client) and am having trouble with the implementation. Essentially I'm creating a button on the front end like this:

`<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadFile()"><i class="fa fa-file-photo-o"></i> Download Screenshot</button>`

And implementing trying to implement it via a click event like this:

```
downloadFile(){
    console.log('Connecting to sftp...');
    var ftpClient = require('ftp-client'),
        config = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 22,
            user: 'anonymous',
            password: 'anonymous'
        },
        options = {
            logging: 'basic'
        },
        client = new ftpClient(config, options);

    console.log('Downloading Screenshot...');
    client.connect(function () {
        client.download('/sftFilepPath', './Downloads', {
            overwrite: 'none'
        }, function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
}
```

I keep getting an error, however saying: `TypeError: Socket is not a constructor` whenever the button is pressed. I'm getting both of my console.log() calls to show in the debugger so I assume it has to do with where I'm trying to actually connect and download.

I tried calling import for the FtpClient namespace and making a private client parameter in the constructor and working off of that, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I know a constructor is implicitly called by the new keyword, but I don't reference 'Socket' anywhere in my code. Maybe I'm missing something?

Here is my imports and constructor for reference:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { TestInstance, Test, TestDetails } from '../../objModules/index';
import { RunServices } from './run.services';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as _ from 'underscore';
import { ModalController } from './run.modal.controller';
// import { FtpClient } from 'ftp-client';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './run.modal.component.html',
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'app-test-data',
    providers: [ RunServices ]
})

export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    testInstance: TestDetails;
    id: string;
    private element: JQuery;

    private runId: string;
    private test$: Observable<Test>;
    private testHistory$: Observable<TestInstance[]>;

    private test: Test;
    private testHistory: TestInstance[];
    private selectedTest: TestInstance;
    private latestRuns: TestInstance[];

    private averagePass: number;
    private averageFail: number;

    services: RunServices;

    constructor(private modalController: ModalController, private el: ElementRef, private runServices: RunServices) {
        this.element = $(el.nativeElement);
        this.services = runServices;

        // Initialize these objects so we don't get any errors
        this.test = new Test(' ', ' ', ' ', [' '], ' ', ' ');
        this.testHistory = new Array<TestInstance>(new TestInstance(' ', ' ', ' ', 0, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '));
        this.testInstance = new TestDetails(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 0, null, ' ');
        this.selectedTest = new TestInstance(' ', ' ', ' ', 0, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your ftp client is too old. System environments change more and more rapidly. But this client hasn't been updated since 2015. Try to use an up-to-date client like [jsftp](http://github.com/sergi/jsftp)

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem or answered your question.

Comment: That's fair. I'll try out jsftp and if it works I'll mark the answer accordingly.

Comment: I still cannot seem to get it to work. Now I'm getting the error `TypeError: createConnection is not a function' when the click event is fired. I posted another question using jsftp [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660406/jsftp-typeerror-createconnection-is-not-a-function).

Comment: Browsing through some posts like this github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/1780 I guess that JS based FTP-Clients are not supposed to run in a browser for security reasons. You have to build up your own server and implement the client there. Only then you can access the Net module which is not reachable out of the browser and causes the error you mention. This seems to be a general issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial Overview**

There is an anomaly is your file path within the `client.download` method. The path `/stfFilepPath` seems to have an extra 'p'. Try removing it unless that is the actual name of the path.

So;

`client.download('/sftFilepPath', './Downloads'`

becomes

`client.download('/sftFilePath', './Downloads'`

Try it out and let me know if it works. If not try Lynx's solution.

Comment: The file path I listed there wasn't the actual one I tried to use. I'm pretty sure that wouldn't of caused the error that I'm facing if that was the case. I did double check my file paths in my code and they do seem correct.